# Why my app is unsearchable on mobile devices? [native-platform option in developer console]

Tags: native, google-play, platform

My apk file is uploaded and published on google play store about 7 days ago. The app is searchable on PC, but is unsearchable on mobile devices. Even I enter the download page by pakage name, it only shows **"This app is incompatible with all of your devices"**.

I get into developer console to see the information of the app. The option ,"Supported Devices", shows **"This application is available to over 0 devices"**.

It really confuse me. And then I get into the apk info, I found a weird option ,"native-platform".

API level: 8-17+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all
**Native platforms: JsonRpc2-Base-1.25.1**

Is that means the app only available on the devices with jsonrpc2-base-1.25.1? If so, I did use the json api(jsonrpc2-base-1.25.1.jar), but it was included in the app. I have no idea why it requires the native platform. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: I removed JsonRpc2-Base-1.25.1.jar and other API that uses JSON, then it works! There must be something wrong with the APIs.

Comment: It shows "This application is available to over 2098 devices", and the Native platform option is gone now.